# FSharp: Why `select` clause cannot be placed before `where` in query expression?

Tags: .net, linq, f#

```
query {
    for i in [|1;2;3;4|] do
    select i   // ERROR: FS0001
    where (i = 26)
}

query {
    for i in [|1;2;3;4|] do
    where (i = 26)
    select i
} // OK
```

The compiler reports FS0001 for the first query, on `select i`. According to https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/Query.fsi

```
member Select : source:QuerySource<'T,'Q> * [<ProjectionParameter>] projection:('T -> 'Result) -> QuerySource<'Result,'Q>
member Where : source:QuerySource<'T,'Q> * [<ProjectionParameter>] predicate:('T -> bool) -> QuerySource<'T,'Q>
```

`Select` and `Where` have same type of first parameter, and similar return type. Why their order matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the reason after some research.

Function `Where` has `MaintainsVariableSpace` attribute while `Select` not. That's why `i` is invisible for the `where` clause after `select` clause.